# How to add HTML using Nodejs?

Tags: html, node.js

I should add HTML text in document and then send it to a server using Express.js. Which libraries can help me to add HTML? Except Ejs

Answer (score 1):

You should use a templat engine: [Using template engines with Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html):

> A template engine enables you to use static template files in your application. At runtime, the template engine replaces variables in a template file with actual values, and transforms the template into an HTML file sent to the client. This approach makes it easier to design an HTML page.

A simple `res.sendFile()` should do the job: [How To Deliver HTML Files with Express](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-deliver-html-files):

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// sendFile will go here
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started at http://localhost:' + port);
```

Comment: ok, but if i should change something in this file?

Comment: you mean a dynamic html file?

Comment: You should use a templat engine: [Using template engines with Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)